# Cant get partial application and async play together in flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a function (partial application) that either returns a function if only the first param is passed or executes entirely in case it receives the necessary params.

Here's reproducing code :

```
    /* @flow */

   type Doer = (name: string, ...args: mixed[]) => Promise<number>[];
   type LaterDoer = (name: string, ...args: mixed[]) => Promise<boolean>;

   const partial = (
        doSomething: Doer,
        name?: string,
        ...args?: mixed[]): Promise<boolean> | LaterDoer => {

      const doTheThing = async (name: string, ...args: mixed[]): Promise<boolean> => {

        const results = doSomething(name, ...args);
        const resolved = await Promise.all(results);

        return resolved[0] === 1 && resolved[1] === 2;
      };

      return name ? doTheThing(name, ...args) : doTheThing;
   };

   (async ()=>{

     const doesSomething = () => [Promise.resolve(1), Promise.resolve(2)];

     //#1 can work with all required args - returns immediatley
     const now = await partial(doesSomething, "test", 1,2,3);

     //#2 partial application - returns function to be called later with the rest...
     const later = partial(doesSomething);

     const theEnd = await later("test", 1,2,3);

   })();
```

see at [try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAodAXAngBwKZgAiceATmALxgAUAdgIYC2eAXGAM4akCWtA5gBowAOlH1Sfdm0bcAHngAmAbQC6ASkoA+MAAVScGezwAeWgFdGAIzKbVAblTZ8YADL0MZYmUo0GzNpw8-EKiwuKS0nKKqhoU2noG3EbGlnBwMHj0tJoOqADGcLScYDjiGNz0MD7UqACQtQpwAMoGeBgAFrx8bF6kAnW1fngA-AFcXf31oeHso2Ay8srqbAmGJqnpmdlgAD6u7p4k5HFgAN7otQVFGGCNACrteA9dPvTsWLR5vkysHOPBIjEEik8yiSzUK30axSaQyWW0J3OAyuxVIeHYZhgGHYPkaLWYHS6dB+ISBkjUDnqKJuaPY6QAbopXgh6NwbqskngwjAYNRaZjsRSLrU0RgzKRaGBaQzogAGFSUChUACMYAAZGqpeiZcplQqlVQAEyUgC+uRFbXFkqGYGGtzgDyenX4xOYpLCwI0bHuj2e-AcZvQ1DeHy+1DUcXOYDAqGj1Pt6PxbWdfGqsW0Sg5RmE0pgjOoyrUQizXNz+cNahUDhj0eAwAAxKq8lkwAg4KQANattntMCVKpogCOZm4aIUfeBYAAtFqxRKcdxGMwFBUMBksLGwPHaIhmaybqVSOVKtRGonWoSAQAiDycK9CZUCQ0CADMQujm7r9cNJTKFSq9A4DgMDcM25SFNOs5WjiUBmJ84GShgcBgNYW79kyMAHOQCA9mAHQELSGChJu8aYR4xy-ke-6niQ7BJpefDvh+caFMU+EAKK0OOVD0CybJgGRZDUDe6IYPeYCPs+b7VjGJpqOGdhAA)

I get this error for the second option:

> 33:   const theEnd = await later("test", 1,2,3);
>                                  ^ Cannot call `later` because a call signature declaring the expected parameter / return type is missing in
>   `Promise` [1](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAodAXAngBwKZgAiceATmALxgAUAdgIYC2eAXGAM4akCWtA5gBowAOlH1Sfdm0bcAHngAmAbQC6ASkoA+MAAVScGezwAeWgFdGAIzKbVAblTZ8YADL0MZYmUo0GzNpw8-EKiwuKS0nKKqhoU2noG3EbGlnBwMHj0tJoOqADGcLScYDjiGNz0MD7UqACQtQpwAMoGeBgAFrx8bF6kAnW1fngA-AFcXf31oeHso2Ay8srqbAmGJqnpmdlgAD6u7p4k5HFgAN7otQVFGGCNACrteA9dPvTsWLR5vkysHOPBIjEEik8yiSzUK30axSaQyWW0J3OAyuxVIeHYZhgGHYPkaLWYHS6dB+ISBkjUDnqKJuaPY6QAbopXgh6NwbqskngwjAYNRaZjsRSLrU0RgzKRaGBaQzogAGFSUChUACMYAAZGqpeiZcplQqlVQAEyUgC+uRFbXFkqGYGGtzgDyenX4xOYpLCwI0bHuj2e-AcZvQ1DeHy+1DUcXOYDAqGj1Pt6PxbWdfGqsW0Sg5RmE0pgjOoyrUQizXNz+cNahUDhj0eAwAAxKq8lkwAg4KQANattntMCVKpogCOZm4aIUfeBYAAtFqxRKcdxGMwFBUMBksLGwPHaIhmaybqVSOVKtRGonWoSAQAiDycK9CZUCQ0CADMQujm7r9cNJTKFSq9A4DgMDcM25SFNOs5WjiUBmJ84GShgcBgNYW79kyMAHOQCA9mAHQELSGChJu8aYR4xy-ke-6niQ7BJpefDvh+caFMU+EAKK0OOVD0CybJgGRZDUDe6IYPeYCPs+b7VjGJpqOGdhAA).
>           References:
>           10:       ...args?: mixed[]): Promise | LaterDoer => {
>                                     ^ [1](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAodAXAngBwKZgAiceATmALxgAUAdgIYC2eAXGAM4akCWtA5gBowAOlH1Sfdm0bcAHngAmAbQC6ASkoA+MAAVScGezwAeWgFdGAIzKbVAblTZ8YADL0MZYmUo0GzNpw8-EKiwuKS0nKKqhoU2noG3EbGlnBwMHj0tJoOqADGcLScYDjiGNz0MD7UqACQtQpwAMoGeBgAFrx8bF6kAnW1fngA-AFcXf31oeHso2Ay8srqbAmGJqnpmdlgAD6u7p4k5HFgAN7otQVFGGCNACrteA9dPvTsWLR5vkysHOPBIjEEik8yiSzUK30axSaQyWW0J3OAyuxVIeHYZhgGHYPkaLWYHS6dB+ISBkjUDnqKJuaPY6QAbopXgh6NwbqskngwjAYNRaZjsRSLrU0RgzKRaGBaQzogAGFSUChUACMYAAZGqpeiZcplQqlVQAEyUgC+uRFbXFkqGYGGtzgDyenX4xOYpLCwI0bHuj2e-AcZvQ1DeHy+1DUcXOYDAqGj1Pt6PxbWdfGqsW0Sg5RmE0pgjOoyrUQizXNz+cNahUDhj0eAwAAxKq8lkwAg4KQANattntMCVKpogCOZm4aIUfeBYAAtFqxRKcdxGMwFBUMBksLGwPHaIhmaybqVSOVKtRGonWoSAQAiDycK9CZUCQ0CADMQujm7r9cNJTKFSq9A4DgMDcM25SFNOs5WjiUBmJ84GShgcBgNYW79kyMAHOQCA9mAHQELSGChJu8aYR4xy-ke-6niQ7BJpefDvh+caFMU+EAKK0OOVD0CybJgGRZDUDe6IYPeYCPs+b7VjGJpqOGdhAA)

as I do in my application's code.

running the first option:

```
const theEnd = await partial(doesSomething, "test", 1,2,3);
```

doesnt cause any flow errors.

I cant figure out what's missing here and google didnt find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand the logic here, when `partial` is called it should return function, so it should be:

```js
const partial = (
        doSomething: Doer) => 
        (name?: string,
        ...args?: mixed[]): Promise<boolean> | LaterDoer => {
```

instead of

```js
const partial = (
        doSomething: Doer,
        name?: string,
        ...args?: mixed[]): Promise<boolean> | LaterDoer => {
```

Check it in [flow try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAodAXAngBwKZgAiceATmALxgAUAdgIYC2eAXGAM4akCWtA5gBowAOlH1Sfdm0bcAHngAmAbQC6ASkoA+MAAVScGezwAeWgFdGAIzKbVAblTZ8YADL0MZYmUo0GzNpw8-EKiwuKS0nKKqhoU2noG3EbGlnBwMHj0tJoOqADGcLScYDjiGNz0MD7UqACQtQpwAMoGeBgAFrx8bF6ksdp1tXRMeAD8AVxdAoOh4ezjYDLyyupsCYYmqemZ2WAAPq7uniTkcWAA3ui1BUUYYI0AKu14T10+9OxYtHm+IxNBghEYgkUkWURWajW+g2KTSGSy2jOl0GN2KpDw7DMMAw7B8jRazA6XWGzBCwMkagc9VRd3R7HSADdFO8EPRuHd1kk8GEYDBqHSsTjKVdauiMGZSLQwHTGdEAAwqSgUKgARjAADJ1dKMbLlCrFcqqAAmKkAX1yoraEqlfgIo3ucCeL06-BJeDJYRBGjYj2er34DnN6GoHy+P2oajilzAYFQMZpDoxBLaLr41X6YCUnKMwhlMCZ1BVaiE2e5eYLRrUKgcsfjhWKMCOpxKZQqfMaSdaRP4wpjtbACY6eAAorQFCy2XdGx5SNQAEQeThzoQqgRGgQAZl7sdNagjdiAA).

Comment: thanks @frontendgirl but that's not what I was trying to do exactly. partial can either return the result directly (when passed enough arguments) or return a function that will give the results once its passed the rest of the arguments. ive updated the try in the original question